# I can't make the right query in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables in my database:

**programme**

[image: pragrame table]

**course**

[image: course table]

**users**

[image: users table]

**payment**

[image: payment table]

I want to select all the courses that a specific user has not made payment to. The fields: course id, course image,course name, and programme name should be present and not null;

When i run this:

```
SELECT course.course_id,course.course_name,course.image,course.amount,course.course_name, 
programme.prog_name, payment.user_id 
FROM course
INNER JOIN programme ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
LEFT JOIN payment ON course.course_id = payment.course_id
WHERE payment.user_id = 21;
```

I only get courses the user has made payment to:

[image: result]

I want really tried several ways though but nothing works for me.

This is the users dashboard.
[users dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgYJs.jpg)

So if the user login and make payment, I don't want to show the course he/she has made payment to again.

sample of php code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Image</th>                                               
         <th>Course Name</th>                                           
         <th>Category</th>                                          
         <th>Amount</th>                                           
         <th>Enroll</th>                                           
            </tr>
               </thead>
                  <tbody>
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT
    course.course_id,course.course_name,course.amount,course.image, 
    programme.prog_name FROM course INNER JOIN programme ON course.prog_id = 
    programme.prog_id";


$result = query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $course_id = $row["course_id"];
      $image = $row["image"];
      $course_name = $row["course_name"];
      $prog_name = $row['prog_name'];
      $amount = $row["amount"];
                                                        
        ?>
     <tr>
    <td><span class="list-img"><img src="images/course/<?php echo $image ?>.jpg"
    alt=""></span></td>
    <td><span class="list-enq-name"><?php  echo $course_name; ?></span></a></td>
    <td><?php  echo $prog_name; ?></td>
    <td><span class="list-enq-name"><?php  echo $amount; ?></span></td>
    <td>
    <a href="http://localhost:90/work/students/purchase_course.php?img=<?php
    echo $image ?>&course_id=<?php echo $course_id ?>&course_name=<?php echo
    $course_name; ?>&prog_name=<?php echo $prog_name ?>&amount=<?php echo 
    $amount ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light  btn">REGISTER</a> 

                </td>                    
             </tr>
<?php }   ?>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Because, if a user did not made a payment, there is no record in payment table... you cant query `WHERE payment.user_id = xx`, as you mentioned it will only give you the records _with_ payment. Either you need to create payment records with `ammount = 0` (hasn't payed), or you'll need to query for `payment.uer_id IS NULL` to the those without a payment record.

Comment: You don´t have any relation between the user and the program_id, so if you don´t know which program the user is in, you don´t know wich courses he should pay.

Comment: @HonkderHase payment.user_id IS NULL,  gives me all the records of courses where users have not made payment to. What I really want is to select all courses a specific user say user_id = 21 has not made payment to;

Comment: @nacho users can enroll in any course, so far as they can pay and the course.prog_id determines which course belong to which program.

Comment: Then you'll need a connection between users and courses (m:n relation table inbetween)

Comment: just as an aside - using `aliases` for the table names would make the query a little easier to both read and write

Comment: @HonkderHase There is already M:N relation in between courses and users  in the payment table. As soon as  users make  payment, they are assigned a course_id for the course they made payment for and the user_id is stored also to know the user who made payment for which course.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Alright I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got what I what.

I found out that after running my query,

```
SELECT course.course_id,course.course_name,course.image,course.amount,course.course_name, 
programme.prog_name, payment.user_id 
FROM course
INNER JOIN programme ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
LEFT JOIN payment ON course.course_id = payment.course_id
WHERE payment.user_id = 21;
```

if I could compare the course.course_id with all the courses through a loop, I could get all the courses that a specific user has made payment to;

After getting this idea, I want further to test that and see by modifying my query to look like this:

```
SELECT course.course_id,course.course_name,course.image,course.amount,course.course_name, 
programme.prog_name, payment.user_id 
FROM course
INNER JOIN programme ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
LEFT JOIN payment ON course.course_id = payment.course_id
WHERE payment.user_id = 21 AND course.course_id = 10;
```

[image: result from the query]

Indeed this proved it.

So I want further to modify my code, Because I didn't need to select a lot of fields to get that done

```
   SELECT course.course_id,payment.user_id
   FROM course INNER JOIN programme
   ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
   INNER JOIN payment
   course.course_id = payment.course_id
   WHERE payment.user_id = 21
   AND course.course_id = 10;
```

I then integrated this into my php code where I ran a loop to get all the course displayed.

php code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Image</th>                                               
         <th>Course Name</th>                                           
         <th>Category</th>                                          
         <th>Amount</th>                                           
         <th>Enroll</th>                                           
            </tr>
               </thead>
                  <tbody>
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT
    course.course_id,course.course_name,course.amount,course.image, 
    programme.prog_name FROM course INNER JOIN programme ON course.prog_id = 
    programme.prog_id";


$result = query($sql); //query() custom function = mysqli_query()
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $course_id = $row["course_id"];
      $image = $row["image"];
      $course_name = $row["course_name"];
      $prog_name = $row['prog_name'];
      $amount = $row["amount"];
                                                        
        ?>
     <tr>
    <td><span class="list-img"><img src="images/course/<?php echo $image ?>.jpg"
    alt=""></span></td>
    <td><span class="list-enq-name"><?php  echo $course_name; ?></span></a></td>
    <td><?php  echo $prog_name; ?></td>
    <td><span class="list-enq-name"><?php  echo $amount; ?></span></td>
     <?php

//modification to php code

    $sql2 = "SELECT course.course_id,payment.user_id
            FROM course INNER JOIN programme
            ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
            INNER JOIN payment
            course.course_id = payment.course_id
            WHERE payment.user_id = 21
            AND course.course_id = $course_id"; // comparing course id with the while loop one 
    $result2 = query($sql2);
    if(row_count($result2) > 0){ //row count..custom func = mysqli_num_rows
     ?>
     <td>
    <a href="http://localhost:90/work/students/purchase_course.php?img=<?php
    echo $image ?>&course_id=<?php echo $course_id ?>&course_name=<?php echo
    $course_name; ?>&prog_name=<?php echo $prog_name ?>&amount=<?php echo 
    $amount ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light  btn" disabled>REGISTERED</a><!-- disabled button if user has paid for a course -->
     </td>

     <?php }else{ ?>
     <td>
    <a href="http://localhost:90/work/students/purchase_course.php?img=<?php
    echo $image ?>&course_id=<?php echo $course_id ?>&course_name=<?php echo
    $course_name; ?>&prog_name=<?php echo $prog_name ?>&amount=<?php echo 
    $amount ?>" class="waves-effect waves-light  btn">REGISTER</a> 
   </td>

  <?php } ?>   
   </tr>

  <?php } ?>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: User dashbord looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT course.course_id,course.course_name,course.image,course.amount,course.course_name, 
programme.prog_name, payment.user_id 
FROM course
INNER JOIN programme ON programme.prog_id = course.prog_id
LEFT JOIN payment ON course.course_id = payment.course_id
WHERE payment.user_id = 21;
```